# How to search words in a varchar column?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have this table :

[image: materials table]

I want to search for material_name by specific way :

for example :if I have a material named (my new product 2014)

if the user press (m n p 2), (m e d 0), (y w c 1), (my w uc), (my), (m n)...(where first part of the interred string refer to first word of the material name and the second for second and so on)(when user press space, the function should start look to next word )  ... the material should be one of  selected materials
and search function called on `TextChange` event.

In my situation which better, to make the search function in the application , or in the sql ?
and why ?

knowing that : the materials table may contain 10000 materials

can you help me?

Comment: What means _press (m n p 2), (m e d 0), (y w c 1), (my w uc),..._?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TimSchmelter first part of the string refer to the first word of the material name and the second for second and so on

Comment: I would avoid making a DB call in the textchanged event, unless your list of products is 6 figures I would download a list of items and filter in code.

Comment: Also, whilst you may disagree, this seems like a *terrible* design decision - I can't see how searching this way makes any sense at all?  IF the user knows the letters, why can't they just type a "phrase" and you do a `LIKE` search?

Comment: @Moo-Juice this is sort of like CamelHump searching in ReSharpers find dialog.  if you are familiar with the materials it can be significantly quicker, especially if it does a partial match

Comment: @Moo-Juice I want to create this function to make my application more user friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would probably be best creating and index containing the first letter/ number of word of each material and then searching on that.

So you have a table containing the values your users will type (mnp2, med0, ywc1 etc etc) and then the material_id you can use to look up the actual material name, then select the material with the matching name from your list.

Alternatively (and maybe simpler) just create this index in memory on the client from the list when you start up then search the index for what your clients have typed and select the relevant item in the list.  So create a representation of your list with the short version of your material and the position in the list:

```
mnp2,0
med0,1
ywc1,2
```

etc etc

then match the users keypresses to this list (using `StartsWith` is probably best) and select the elelment from the list in the appropriate position

Comment: in this way the index table my contain more than 1000000 rows for 10000 materials
I think the performance  will be bad!!

Comment: no the index contains 1 row per material ie mnp2, med0 etc etc